# MongoDB $match by array subset

Tags: mongodb, match

In a MongoDB storing objects the form of

```
{ array: ["a", "b", "c", ... ] }
{ array: ["a", "d", "f", ... ] }
...
```

I want to retrieve all objects having e.g. `"b"` **or** `"d"` as values in their `array` field. How can I do this? What I tried is

```
{ $match: { array: { $all: [ "b", "d" ] } } }
```

but this requires `"b"` **and** `"d"` to be present in order to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `$or` operator with a simple query on the `array` field, or an $in operation as Sammaye points out below (which will be more performant):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/#op._S_or

```
> db.coll.insert({ array: ["a", "b", "c"] })
> db.coll.insert({ array: ["a", "d", "f"] })
>
> db.coll.find({ array : 'b' })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7aa881e227fe57ccb569"), "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
>
> db.coll.find({ array : 'a' })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7aa881e227fe57ccb569"), "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7ab481e227fe57ccb56a"), "array" : [ "a", "d", "f" ] }
```

$in:

```
> db.coll.find({ array : { $in : ['a', 'b'] } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7aa881e227fe57ccb569"), "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7ab481e227fe57ccb56a"), "array" : [ "a", "d", "f" ] }

> db.coll.find({ array : { $in : ['c', 'z'] } }) 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7aa881e227fe57ccb569"), "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

$or:

```
> db.coll.find({ $or : [ { array  : 'a' }, { array : 'b' } ] })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7aa881e227fe57ccb569"), "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7ab481e227fe57ccb56a"), "array" : [ "a", "d", "f" ] }
>
> db.coll.find({ $or : [ { array  : 'c' }, { array : 'z' } ] })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cc7aa881e227fe57ccb569"), "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

If you add an index on the array field these queries will be faster.

Comment: The $in operator would be much better to use here, in fact the $or operator would be quite unperformant for this query

Comment: Presuming there is an index, I think it really depends on the data and how many hits/misses one gets on the query. If I do explains on both query patterns the nscanned can be higher with the $in query.  Do you have any examples showing how $or is a bad option?

Comment: Nah, an $or is processed differently to how it is in SQL. It is like sending off a separate query for each clause (hence the fact that each clause uses a separate index) and then merging duplicates when they are returned. $or is quite lengthy process actually. $in will show more scans since you may have only been looking at one clause of the $or

Comment: Thanks for the comments and explanation...answer updated and your comment upvoted!